# IE7/8 Unexpected Object Error in HTML5 Boilerplate

Tags: jquery, internet-explorer, html5boilerplate

I am using HTML5 Boilerplate on a project. Unfortunately I am getting these SCRIPT438 errors in IE 7/8 which prevents my jQuery from running. The dev site is here http://clintongreen.com/clients/researchreview/index.html

```
**ERRORS**
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'hoverIntent' 
plugins.js, line 47 character 5
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'accordionza' 
script.js, line 31 character 2
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'nivoSlider' 
script.js, line 3 character 5
```

Please help if you can, this is really bugging me, thanks

Comment: did you try jquery conflict ?

Comment: Hi, sorry for a dumb question but do you have any idea where I should add the no-conflict script in. Boilerplate has all your scripts in one page so I tried adding it at the top of the page but I was getting undefined errors for the no-conflict. Thanks

Comment: After some work I have it down to 2 errors, SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'hoverIntent' 
plugins.js, line 47 character 5
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'nivoSlider' 
script.js, line 3 character 5, but I still can't get ti to work with no-conflict :(

Comment: Ok solved it, It was just a case of ordering everything the right way, damn you IE, damn you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for everyone who has this recurring problem of SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'BlahBlahBlah' on old versions of IE but everything works fine on modern browsers.

The problem here was the stacking order, where the modern browsers seem to read your scripts as a whole and then figures out what to with it, the older browsers seem to read it line by line.

So I had one long js page for all my plugins, and I added jQuery UI at the bottom but some of the other plugins I added at the top relied on jQuery UI so it gave an error. Once I changed everything to the correct order it all worked fine. CHeers